# Nginx, html5 audio and access restriction

Tags: nginx, html5-audio, mediaelement.js, restriction, content-disposition

I have a (Wordpress) site where I publish mp3 files. Each page features one single mp3 file which can be downloaded by pressing a download button, or played on-page in a built-in mediaelement.js player.

Mediaelement.js is configured to first try flash, then fallback to html5 audio.

Furthermore, I need to make sure the mp3's are only downloadable by logged-in users.

I have the following rule in my nginx.conf:

```
location ~* \.(mov|mp3)$ {
    if ($http_cookie !~ "wordpress_logged_in") {
        return 403;
    }
    add_header Content-Disposition "attachment";
}
```

(The add_header is needed for the file to start downloading instead of playing when clicked on the download button, the button is a direct link to the mp3 file stored on the server.)

Now, it works great overall (the cookie check, the player, the click to download part) in major desktop browsers. The problem is — the audio player fails to play audio in Chrome under Android (where it uses html5 audio instead of flash) — nothing happens when I press the play button, as if the player can't locate the file. The download button works fine.

If I remove the cookie check, the player starts working as expected in Chrome/Android.

I have a feeling I am missing something very obvious in this setup, but can't quite put my finger on it. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: This cannot be all relevant settings, as the player would never work without being logged in. Please show the full configuration dealing with mp3 files.

Comment: I have the impression that the playback of the audio file is made by another component of the browser, so it doesn't send the cookie.

Comment: @Melvyn The player is rendered on-page for logged in users only through the native wordpress function is_user_logged_in() (as well as the download button). The cookie check is meant to block direct requests to the mp3 file (http://example.com/audio/file.mp3) from anonymous users.